# How update only the children calling save in hierarchy?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Mother(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()

class Father(Mother):
    default = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.default:
            Father.objects.update(default=False)
        super(Father, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ChildOne(Father):
    a_attribute = models.AttributeField()

class ChildTwo(Father):
    b_attribute = models.AttributeField()
```

If I call `childtwo.save()`, how do I make sure all `childone` do not get updated? Is it possibly to modify the save method in Father's class to distinguish between the children calling `save()`? I mean, without overriding `Father`'s save method in all classes I inherent it.

Comment: Having a `class Father` that inherits the `class Mother`, and beyond that, having classes like `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo`, both of them inheriting `Father` is a very awkward approach. Simply putting your code into classes doesn't make automatically OOP. In python there is also multiple inheritance. Why do you need `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo`. Can't they have more than 2 children?

Comment: What do you imagine the table structure to be for these classes. Are all of these concrete objects in the DB? or is it just the `Mother` class which is concrete?

Comment: This is a simplification of my classes. They contain other attributes. All of them are concrete database objects.

Comment: No, this is simplification of your complication. Why then do you need this inheritance: `Mother -> Father -> ChildOne`? Please explain what you really want to achieve. Your problem is not in your question, your problem is in the approach that led to that question.

Comment: Because father has attributes I don't want Mother to have, and so does ChildOne and Two. These are just simple examples in this post. The question is just to know if I can bulk update only the class calling the method from Father without having to override it in the child's class.

Comment: "Because father has attributes I don't want Mother to have" -> that doesn't make it necessary to have class inheritance like yours. Your question is still not very clear. Why do you need `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo`? Please explain what you really want to achieve, before writing the code.

Comment: Cezar, I understand your interest, but my question is whether I can achieve what I am mentioning or not. This is not about how the classes are constructed. Otherwise I'll just override the save method.